# SQL for update in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I do a select in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = 5
```

the results appear in the grid. I'd like edit this record in the grid, change values and save, Is it possible? Other way (other than make an date query)? Other tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one simple way is to open the object explorer and right click on the table name and select 'edit top 200 rows' option.

Comment: After you click "edit top 200 rows", there is a button on the top-left corner that says "SQL", once you click it, you can do your query and edit values

Comment: The record is may be not in the top 200 rows

Comment: as @Lamak said you can open the query and remove the top (200) from the query to view all the records to edit

Comment: Isn't there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the table and select edit option. If you want to use the query pane, then you write an update statement.
The results pane from a query is just that, it's not the table. After all it might be a view or a join or a union...